# SQL: How to find most common key-value pair in a jsonb?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Given a table where one of the columns has type jsonb, how does one find the most common key-value pairs among all records in that column?

The dict is only one level deep.

Comment: How do you know the JSONBLOB contains key/value pairs?  Perhaps some sample data and desired results would clarify what you want.

Answer (score 1):

If your json has only one level is ease, here is a test code:

```
-- Test Table:
CREATE TEMP TABLE test (id serial,data jsonb);
-- Test Data
INSERT INTO test(data) VALUES
('{"a":{"a1":{"a2":1}},"b":2,"c":3}'::jsonb),
('{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3}'::jsonb),
('{"a":1}'::jsonb);
```

To get all keys, there is a function called `jsonb_object_keys` but only gets the set of keys in the outermost JSON object. So the query to get all the keys is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT key, COUNT(*) OVER(partition by key)
FROM
(SELECT jsonb_object_keys(data) AS key  FROM test)keys;
```

The result is:

```
key | count
----+-------
c   | 2
b   | 2
a   | 3
```

From that result you can get which key is the most used. f you want to get pairs... you just have to tweak a little this query... It would be better if you give an example data.

If you want to get the keys from a nested json... That's harder. You would have to create a PL code that recursively goes through the JSON to get witch keys are more used.

Comment: Yes, just one level. How would you tweak the query for pairs?

Comment: I would need an example of the pairs to see how the query should be. But, basically, you have to see how to group the pairs to have the result by pairs.